# Upload photos to website from a text to a 1-800 number from mobile phone

Tags: text, web, upload, mobile, photo

I need the ability for someone to send a text with a photo attached to a 1-800 number from their mobile phone, and have that image uploaded/sent to a website.  I'm at a bit of a loss on where to start with this.  Can anyone point me in the right direction or let me know what would be involved and how to get started?  Any insight is appreciated.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Sry i don´t know usa numbering. But if you need send image in sms, then you need a [MMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimedia_Messaging_Service) [gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MM7_%28MMS%29) for receving.